# How can we find out the deleted record in After delete trigger?

Tags: trigger, delete, after-trigger

I am writing a trigger to handle after insert,after update and after delete events.
I am using trigger.old for after delete.But, how to differentiate the deleted record from the rest of the records of the object?

What I have done so far is :

```
List<Object__c) lstTriggerOld = trigger.old;
List<Object__c> lstAllRecords = [SELECT Id FROM Object__c WHERE ID != NULL];
List<Object__c> deletedRecords = [SELECT Id FROM Object__c WHERE ID IN :lstTriggerOld AND ID NOT IN : lstAllRecords ];
```

But the last list is not fetching any rows.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get or Query deleted records you need to use `ALL ROWS` So your query will be

`List<Object__c> deletedRecords = [SELECT Id FROM Object__c WHERE ID IN :lstTriggerOld AND ID NOT IN : lstAllRecords  ALL ROWS];`

[All Rows Keyword](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_query_all_rows.htm)